# switchtowindow is not working in Firefox and IE selenium webdriver 3.4.0

Tags: selenium-webdriver

The below code working fine in Chrome but not working in Firefox and IE

```
public static Object[] switchToAnotherWindow()
{
    Set<String> windows=SeleniumMethods.getDriver().getWindowHandles();
    Object[] window=windows.toArray();  
    SeleniumMethods.getDriver().switchTo().window((String) window[(windows.size()-1)]);
    System.out.println("windows"+windows.toString());
    System.out.println("switched to Another window"+(windows.size()-1));
    SeleniumMethods.getLogger().log(LogStatus.INFO, "Switcing to Last Opened/Another window");
    return window;
}

public static void switchtoRequiredWindow(Object[] windows,int window)
{
    SeleniumMethods.getDriver().switchTo().window((String) windows[window]);
    System.out.println("windows"+windows[window]);
    System.out.println("switched to Original window"+window);
    SeleniumMethods.getLogger().log(LogStatus.INFO, "Switching to Required window"+window);
}
```

when I call method like `public static void switchtoRequiredWindow(0)` it is not switching to the original window. Could you please suggest me to work in Firefox and IE?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Hi Kapil,sorry for late response. Actually while navigating to child windows we are not getting any problems but the problem comes when it is switches back parent window.For example if we have 3 windows now it is performed on 3 rd window but it is not switching to second window[parent] . we are not getting any errors in log.It is closing firefox browser.